# How to perform permutation and combination in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

we have a master table

```
Id combination dataid
1   1A,2B      5
2   1B,2A      5
3   1A         5
4   2A         5
5   1B         5
6   2B         5
```

each element in the input create combination and if combination are formed with respect to master table, it should return the first formed combination.

If combination are not forming,it should return the first element from the input which is available in the combination column.

below are some of the desired input and output

input :

```
dataid  value
5       1A,2B,2A

output: id-1 combination- 1A,2B
```

input :

```
dataid  value
5       2B,1A

 output: id-1 combination- 1A,2B
```

Input :

```
dataid  value
5       1B,2A,2B,1A

output : id -2 Combination-1B,2A
```

input :

```
dataid value

5       1B,1A

output : id-5 combination-1B
```

is this can be achievable in SQL Server 2012?

can anyone help on this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data in your table? You should really normalise that? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, combination is required as it has a meaning hence stored it.

Comment: So it's not a delimited value?

Comment: No,it's a pair.

Comment: If the values **aren't** delimited your need to reform your input values then. For example is `'1B,2A,2B,1A'` `'1B,2A` and `'2B,1A'` or perhaps `'1B,2A'`, `'1B'` and `'1A`, or `'1B'`,`'2A'`, `'2B'` and `'1A'`? It's impossible to tell as you're using a delimiter in your data and as a row separator. Put each new value on a new line. it's clearly, however, not `'1B,2A,2B,1A'` as there are no rows with that value.

Comment: Also do the same for the output. For example, you have the output `1A,2B`, but is that `'1A,2B'` with the `ID`  `1`, or `'1A'` and `'2B'` with the `ID`s `3` and `6`? Perhaps, for the outputs, you could include the respected values of `ID`, so we have a clear result set.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Larnu yes the output should be with IDs but input will be like that only.i think, this can be stored in a temp table using split .

Comment: So, what is *"input : 1A,2B,2A"*? None of your rows have the value `'1A,2B,2A'`. As `,` isn't a delimiter (by your own admission), and therefore `1A,2B,2A` **must** be 3 rows, why that that not return IDs 3, 4, and 6?

Comment: *"this can be stored in a temp table using split"* What is split? Do you mean a string spliitter? You said these values are **not** delimited, so you won't need a string splitter. `'1A,2B'` represents a **single** value, not 2.

Comment: No,the input values are delimited values separated by comma however the output is a pair.sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Then my question stands, if `'1A,2B,2A'` represents `'1A'`,`'2B'`,`'2A'` it should return rows 3, 4, and 6, not 1, should it not? ` None of the **single values** `'1A'`,`'2B'`,`'2A'` are the **single value** `'1A,2B'`.

Comment: Actually we need to find out all the possible combination with each other ,if combination is formed then with respect to master tbl ,will pull out that pair else the single value.

Comment: But `'1A,2B'` doesn't equal any of the values; so it cannot be returned. As I said. You've stated yourself that the data stored in the table is **not** delimited data, so for the input values `'1A'`,`'2B'`,`'2A'` the value `'1A,2B'` is not a valid value; as it isn't any of those. if, however, the values ***are*** delimited (and that's what you mean by a pair) then i refer back to my original comment; and you should be fixing the design. either way, what you describe has made no sense, and there's a big lack of explanation.

Comment: If we take example of 1st input 1A,2B,2A .1A will form permutation of 1A,2B and 1A,2A ..now these two permutation will match to master table ,if they match we have to pick the first formed permutation that is 1A,2B

Answer (score 1):

First you need a *splitter* that includes an *ItemNumber*, for that you can use [delimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). That, the `APPLY` operator a `window aggregate function` and some `bitwise` logic and you can do this:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (stringID INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t1 VALUES('1A,2B,2A'),('2B,1A'),('1B,2A,2B,1A'),('1B,1A');

-- Solution
WITH f AS
(
  SELECT
    t.stringID,
    Item = part.One+Part.Two,
    Chk  = COUNT(part.One) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.One ORDER BY s.ItemNumber) &
           COUNT(part.Two) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.Two ORDER BY s.ItemNumber)
  FROM        @t1 AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedSplit8k(t.String,',') AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.Item,1,1),SUBSTRING(s.Item,2,1))) part(One,Two)
)
SELECT ID = f.stringID, item.Combo
FROM   f
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT STUFF((
           SELECT ','+f2.Item
           FROM   f AS f2
           WHERE  f2.Chk = 1 AND f2.stringID = f.stringID
           ORDER BY f2.Item
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
) AS item(Combo)
WHERE CHARINDEX(f.item, item.Combo) & f.Chk = 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID          Combo
----------- ------------
1           1A,2B
2           1A,2B
3           1B,2A
4           1B
```

**UPDATED 2019114 based on OP comments:**

If you can't create a function or something about DelimitedSplit8K is not allowed in PDW you can create an *inline splitter* using XML (not my first choice but its not terrible and will work for what you're doing.)

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (stringID INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t1 VALUES('1A,2B,2A'),('2B,1A'),('1B,2A,2B,1A'),('1B,1A');

WITH f AS
(
  SELECT
    t.stringID,
    Item = part.One+Part.Two,
    Chk  = COUNT(part.One) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.One ORDER BY s.ItemNumber) &
           COUNT(part.Two) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.Two ORDER BY s.ItemNumber)
  FROM        @t1 AS t
  --CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedSplit8k(t.String,',') AS s
  CROSS APPLY 
  (
    SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), x.xxx.value('(text())[1]','varchar(8000)')
    FROM        (VALUES(CAST(CONCAT('<Z><x>',REPLACE(t.string, ',','</x><x>'),'</x></Z>') AS XML))) AS f(NS)
    CROSS APPLY f.NS.nodes('Z/x') AS x(xxx)
  ) AS s(ItemNumber,Item)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.Item,1,1),SUBSTRING(s.Item,2,1))) part(One,Two)
)
SELECT ID = f.stringID, item.Combo
FROM   f
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT STUFF((
           SELECT ','+f2.Item
           FROM   f AS f2
           WHERE  f2.Chk = 1 AND f2.stringID = f.stringID
           ORDER BY f2.Item
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
) AS item(Combo)
WHERE CHARINDEX(f.item, item.Combo) & f.Chk = 1;
```

Also, I remember a similar issue once in PDW where we were able to get around it using a recursive CTE. If you can create functions, you can use this as you splitter:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.rCteSplitter(@string VARCHAR(8000), @delim CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
WITH a(N,X,XX) AS 
(
  SELECT  1, f.CI, SUBSTRING(@string,1,f.CI-1)
  FROM (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delim,@string),0),LEN(@string)+1))) AS f(CI)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  N+1, f.CI, SUBSTRING(@string,X+1,f.CI-X-1)
  FROM   a
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delim,@string,X+1),0),LEN(@string)+1))) AS f(CI)
  WHERE N <= LEN(@string)-LEN(REPLACE(@string,@delim,''))
)
SELECT 
  ItemNumber = a.N,
  ItemIndex  = a.X,
  Item       = a.XX
FROM   a;
GO
```

Then the solution would look like this:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (stringID INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t1 VALUES('1A,2B,2A'),('2B,1A'),('1B,2A,2B,1A'),('1B,1A');

WITH f AS
(
  SELECT
    t.stringID,
    Item = part.One+Part.Two,
    Chk  = COUNT(part.One) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.One ORDER BY s.ItemNumber) &
           COUNT(part.Two) OVER (PARTITION BY t.StringID, part.Two ORDER BY s.ItemNumber)
  FROM        @t1 AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.rCteSplitter(t.String,',') AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.Item,1,1),SUBSTRING(s.Item,2,1))) part(One,Two)
)
SELECT ID = f.stringID, item.Combo
FROM   f
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT STUFF((
           SELECT ','+f2.Item
           FROM   f AS f2
           WHERE  f2.Chk = 1 AND f2.stringID = f.stringID
           ORDER BY f2.Item
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
) AS item(Combo)
WHERE CHARINDEX(f.item, item.Combo) & f.Chk = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, Cant we do it without delimitedSplit8k?also while running this script I am getting the parallel data warehouse features are not enabled

Comment: One last thing - I did a little research. you can't use functions in PDW so the only viable solution for you is to use my example above that does not include the function (the one with the XML code in it)

Comment: I am getting PDW error on `ORDER BY s.ItemNumber ` while assigning it to Chk.  if i remove  ` ORDER BY s.ItemNumber `  its gives soem result without any error. also i was just going through it , we are not matching the result with master table?or am i wrong. Thanks!